# If $|f_n| \to 0$ and $f_n$ are integrable, is it true that $\int |f_n| \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

If $|f_n| \to 0$ and $f_n$ are integrable, is it true that $\int |f_n| \to 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try
$$
f_n=\frac1n\,1_{[0,n^2]}.
$$

For an example on a bounded interval, one can take 
$$
f_n=n\,1_{[1/n,2/n]}.
$$
Then $f_n\to0$, but $\int f_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: How aboutif the interval of integration is bounded?

Comment: @martycohen: I saw your question two years later. I have added an example.